# iPhone accessibility with a 'lightbox' effect

Tags: iphone, accessibility, voiceover

My app presents a menu popup with a kind of lightbox effect - the rest of the screen is dimmed by placing a translucent UIView over it, and I add a UIView containing a few menu options.  When the user selects a menu item, or dismisses it by tapping elsewhere on the screen, the translucent view & the popup menu are removed from view.

I'm struggling to make this accessible.  When the popup appears, it's not preventing background elements from gaining focus with VoiceOver, and you have to swipe through every single element on the page before reaching the menu items.  Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can require iOS 5, set the blackdrop’s accessibilityViewIsModal property to YES.

Comment: That's good to know.  I ended up checking if voiceover was active (UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()), then hiding all the background views while the 'modal' menu is visible.  I might drop that on iOS5 and use the accessibilityViewIsModal flag instead.

Comment: Be aware that VoiceOver users sometimes toggle it off and on while running an app (especially if there are Accessibility issues).